# Discontinuity of a derivative

Tags: limits, derivatives, absolute-value, continuity

We know that if $f'(x)$ is discontinuous at $x_{0}$, then $x_{0}$ is a fundamental essential discontinuity of $f'(x)$ (because derivatives can't have removable discontinuity or a jump discontinuity). So why derivative of absolute value has jump discontinuity in $x=0$?

Comment: At a point where the derivative exists and a sided limit of the derivative exist, they must be equal. This follows from the mean value theorem: $\frac{f(a)-f(b)}{a-b}=f'(c)$ for a point $c$ between $a$ and $b$, by taking limit as $b\to a$ and noting that the left side tends to the derivative at $f'(a)$ and the right, assuming the existence of the limit is forced to also tend to $f'(a)$. As your example shows, the assumption of existence of $f'(a)$ cannot be removed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The theorem that you are using is this:

**Darboux's theorem:** *If $I$ is an interval of $\mathbb R$ and $f\colon I\longrightarrow\mathbb R$ is differentiable, then $f'$ has no jump discontinuities.*

You cannot apply it to the absolute value function and to the point $0$ since that function is *not* differentiable at $0$.